# TP-Link disables WiFi and restarting

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have two issues with my TP-Link TD-W8960N router (Firmware Version: 1.1.1 Build 131129 Rel.49672, Hardware Version: TD-W8960N V5 0x00000001):

1. From time to time (not regularly, once per week, random time) WiFi is set to disabled (Menu Wireless > Basic > Enable Wireless is unchecked). When I turn it on, all the settings are remembered and WiFi starts to work again. Interestingly, it won't happen if I hard reset my PC.
2. When I shut down my PC (not laptop, Mac or whatever), the router *always* restarts its PPPoA connection. In the logs there is a lot of entries similar to:

   ```
   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=pppoa0 OUT= MAC= SRC=216.243.31.2 DST=[my IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=240 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=49658 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
   ```

These logs say (if I'm correct) that the router is doing its job - but what about restarts?

I have no idea what is going on. I'm running Windows 10, virus protection is enabled with Avira, and I've completed a full virus/spyware scan. I've also changed the password and SSID a few times but nothing has changed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have MAC addressing cloning enabled on the router? Perhaps cloning the MAC of the PC.

Comment: @Tyson, disabled ("No routed WAN Service exists, MAC clone disabled.").

Comment: The messages you see are warning messages about your router being scanned by worms on the internet that are trying to take control of it. If the firmware is up to date and the management password is non-trivial, these are nothing to worry about.

Comment: @czachor you're using old TP-Link firmware. From their [support page for TD-W8960N](http://www.tp-link.us/download/TD-W8960N_V5.html#Firmware) the latest version is [**TD-W8960N_V5_141107**](http://www.tp-link.us/resources/software/TD-W8960N_V5_141107.zip) (that's Build 141107). You should update to the latest firmware and see if you still face the same issue.

Comment: @Vinayak omg I have no idea, how I missed it. After update and tests I'll be back here.

Comment: @czachor So did that fix the issue?

Comment: @Vinayak No :( Firmare is updated, and when i restart my PC, now router is restarting not only PPPoA :( About WiFi - tests in progress.

Comment: @czachor Take a [backup of your router config](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-309.html) and [try resetting the router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-140.html). After that, see if it still restarts when your PC shuts down. If it does, try connecting a different PC to the router and shut down that PC. If the router doesn't restart, the problem might lie with your PC. Routers can be sent commands using scripts. Maybe your computer is asking it to restart when it shuts down?